# Property 'openWindow' does not exist on type 'TestController'

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In my test I click on an element and then the new window is opened. But what I need is to check request from the previous window.

I was trying to do this:

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/openwindow.html

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Example page`
    .page `http://www.example.com/`;

test('Open the TestCafe website', async t => {
    await t
        .openWindow('http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe')
        .openWindow('./documentation');

    const localWebsite = await t.openWindow('file://path/to/my/website');
});
```

but I got this error:

```
Property 'openWindow' does not exist on type 'TestController'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test case works fine in the latest version of TestCafe 1.9.0 where this API introduced.

Make sure that you are using a proper [TestCafe version](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/releases).

Comment: Ok, I had to update npm and install testcafe once again.
I had 1.9.0 version but it didn't work ;)